# ASP.NET Declarative binding for Hyperlink Visibility not working

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I have a hyperlink in a usercontrol that I'd like to set visibility by using a declarative property, i.e.

```
<asp:HyperLink ImageUrl="/images/icons/rss.png" Visible="<%# ShowRssIcon %>" ID="FeedHyperLink" runat="server"></asp:HyperLink>
```

However, it always remains visible, even if ShowRssIcon is false. ShowRssIcon is a simple property set on the usercontrol. Even setting ShowRssIcon to always return false results in the hyperlink showing.

However, setting `Visible="false"` or `Visible="true"` manually works as expected. Also, setting the property in the code behind on `Page_Load` event also works.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `<%# expressions` are evaluated at `DataBind()` time, if you used that, then you need to call `DataBind();` method at PreRenderComplete like..

```
protected void Page_PreRenderComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I totally overlooked this part. Time to hit the books and become an ASP.NET guru I guess.

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with the page lifecycle to know why, but Page_PreRenderComplete didn't work for me. However adding the call in Page_PreRender did.

Answer (score 2):

Your snippet doesn't show any call to DataBind so are you sure there is one? BTW if this hyperlink is not in a databound control like ListView or GridView it is far better to set the property from the code behind.